# Проверка наличия подключения к ftp-серверу

Tags: c#, ftp

Пытаюсь сделать обработку ошибок при подключении к ftp-серверу. Выгялядит это пока так:

```
try
{
   FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
   request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);

   request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

   FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

   Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

   Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
   Console.WriteLine("Команда выполнена, статус {0}", response.StatusDescription);

   reader.Close();
   response.Close();
}
catch (UriFormatException)
{
   // тут вызов метода для повторного указания uri,login и password
}
```

Как я могу проверить наличие успешного подключения к серверу, после ввода uri и логина с паролем? Пока обрабатывает ошибку только в том случае, если uri будет такой, например: `string uri = "localhost";`.

Comment: [Перечисление FtpStatusCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.ftpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверку надо производить сразу после того, как осуществлен запрос, то есть после строчки

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Далее ваш сценарий:

```
switch (response.StatusCode)
{
    case FtpStatusCode.AccountNeeded:
     ...
    break;
    case FtpStatusCode.CommandOK:
     ...
    break;
}
```

Все возможные статусы ответа, как уже подмечено, можно посмотреть [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.ftpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. У меня вчера всё таки получилось это сделать, но костылём. Теперь, прочитал ответ и понимаю, что предложенеый вами код выглядит намного изящнее, чем то, что получилось у меня.